# Internet Explorer Deleting Session

Tags: internet-explorer, coldfusion

I have a website, written in ColdFusion, that utilizes CF Session management via the Application.cfc file.  Everything works fine in FF and Chrome, but IE seems to drop the session when I try to navigate through the site.

Basically what happens is I log in, it sets the session info correctly and directs me to the index.cfm page.  On this page I use the session variables to pull back data about the user.  All seems fine to this point, however as soon as I click a link within the page to go to a different area of the site, I get kicked back to the login screen.

Looking further into it, I have a check in place to make sure the session user_id is defined, and if it is not, redirect to the login page.  It's hitting that block of code and redirecting to the login page because my session.user_id is not defined anymore. This ONLY occurs in Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can look for or try to resolve it?

Thank you!!!!

**APPLICATION.CFC**

Below are the settings related to sessions/cookies from my application.cfc

```
<cfset this.name = "MYAPP">
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(4,0,0,0)>
<cfset this.clientManagement = true>
<cfset this.sessionManagement = "yes">
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,4,0,0)>
<cfset this.setClientCookies = false>
<cfset this.setDomainCookies = false>
```

Comment: code would help.  your App.cfc config for example.  Are you using J2EE sessions?

Comment: @SeanCoyne related settings from Application.cfc included above

Comment: I would expect all browsers to be affected by this issue. It's most likely caused by one of your pages containing a link or redirect that doesn't include the cfid and token. If you're doing any redirecting with javascript, that could lead to a cross-browser issue like you are describing.

Comment: @KevinB any suggestions as to how I can correct it?

Comment: First you have to figure out what's causing it. Figure out where the session is lost exactly, then inspect what caused that action.

Comment: I see setClientCookies is set to false. That means you must be manually setting cfid & cftoken on all links to retain session information. Is this happening?

Comment: Is this happening in production or development? If development, are you using a local domain name? If you're using a local domain name, does it have an underscore ("_") in it? If so, that's an invalid character for a domain name and MSIE doesn't play nice with those. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Comment: Issue was related to a problem on the Cold Fusion server itself in the Admin settings.  Thank you for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this same problem, the issue was resolved by turning on J2EE session variables within ColdFusion Administrator.